# Does the Universal Analytics' Ecommerce plugin have to be required multiple times when using multiple trackers?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

When using the multiple tracker support in analytics.js Ecommerce tracking...
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#multitracker

Does ecommerce.js have to be required for each tracker?
Like this... ?

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');  // default tracker object
ga('myTracker.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');  // tracker for another web property
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, be sure to follow the trackerName.pluginName:method method for the transaction objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more information on this from the Google documentation

> You can also use the ecommerce plugin if you have implemented multiple
>   (named) trackers on your page. The plugin works exactly the same as
>   the default tracker, except that the format is:
>   trackerName.pluginName:method. For example if you created a tracker
>   named myTracker:
>
> ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'myTracker'}); You would
>   then load the ecommerce plugin for that named tracker using:
>
> ga('myTracker.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); The to send a
>   transaction, you can create a transaction object and pass it to the
>   named tracker as follows:
>
> var transaction = {   'id': '1234',                    // Transaction
>   ID.   'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',  // Affiliation or store name.
>   'revenue': '11.99',              // Grand Total.   'shipping': '5' ,
>   // Shipping.   'tax': '1.29'                    // Tax. };
>
> ga('myTracker.ecommerce:addTransaction', transaction); Using this
>   syntax, the transaction object can be used on multiple trackers.
>
> Finally you would send the transaction data as follows:
>
> ga('myTracker.ecommerce:send');

Here's the link to the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#multitracker